# PyCharm-Error: Unable to run a program with the existing interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, ide

It's been around one month, opening the project.
Today when I opened the project on PyCharm it is saying "Invalid Python interpreter selected for the project". But while making any project I always create a virtual environment.
[image]
When I select **Add Interpreter** and select an **Existing** interpreter and select **ok**, it just says updating skeleton and nothing happens after that.
[image]
It still says Invalid interpreter.

I know I can just delete the venv folder and Add a new interpreter but to pip install all the libraries again is very time-consuming and frustrating. I have searched throughout the internet but couldn't find anything. Is there any other solution for this?

**Edit:** Not even deleting the venv folder is helping in this case.

Comment: Are you sure that file's still there, and that OneDrive didn't remove it in the name of saving space?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes, I checked it and looks good to me!